# dataframe value diagonal shift row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I would like to have left shift for each row in `df`, like a diagonal shift.
I have df like that:

```
        a1 a2  a3  a4
row1    1   5   5   3
row2    0   4   1   4
row3    0   0   7   6
row4    0   0   0   2
```

and would like to have it like:

```
        a1 a2  a3  a4
row1    1   5   5   3
row2    4   1   4   0
row3    7   6   0   0
row4    2   0   0   0
```

my idea is to use .shift() method for each row depends on the number. But is there better way to solve the task?

my solution is:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
   df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i].shift(periods=-i,  fill_value = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df1 = df.mask(df.eq(0)).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x, key=pd.isnull)), axis = 1).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df1.columns = df.columns
```

Comment: Thank you!! Will play with your idea for sure!

Answer (score 1):

A numpy approach using [`fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr) to flip the location of the zero values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 0, 'row3': 0, 'row4': 0},
    'a2': {'row1': 5, 'row2': 4, 'row3': 0, 'row4': 0},
    'a3': {'row1': 5, 'row2': 1, 'row3': 7, 'row4': 0},
    'a4': {'row1': 3, 'row2': 4, 'row3': 6, 'row4': 2}
})

mask = df.ne(0)
flipped = np.fliplr(mask)
df.values[flipped] = df.values[mask]
df.values[~flipped] = 0
```

`df`:

```
      a1  a2  a3  a4
row1   1   5   5   3
row2   4   1   4   0
row3   7   6   0   0
row4   2   0   0   0
```

---

A similar approach except moves all 0s to the end instead of just flipping:

```
mask = df.ne(0).values
sorted_mask = np.take_along_axis(mask, np.argsort(~mask), axis=1)
df.values[sorted_mask] = df.values[mask]
df.values[~sorted_mask] = 0
```

Modified `df`:

```
      a1  a2  a3  a4
row1   1   0   5   3  # 0 added to a2
row2   0   4   1   4
row3   0   0   7   6
row4   0   0   0   2
```

flip approach:

```
      a1  a2  a3  a4
row1   1   5   0   3  # 0 position has been flipped
row2   4   1   4   0
row3   7   6   0   0
row4   2   0   0   0
```

sort approach:

```
      a1  a2  a3  a4
row1   1   5   3   0  # 0 is at end
row2   4   1   4   0
row3   7   6   0   0
row4   2   0   0   0
```

---

Breakdown of flip approach:

```
mask = df.ne(0)
```

`mask` holds the locations of the non-zero values:

```
         a1     a2     a3    a4
row1   True   True   True  True
row2  False   True   True  True
row3  False  False   True  True
row4  False  False  False  True
```

`flipped` holds the mask with the 0s flipped to the other side:

```
[[ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True False False]
 [ True False False False]]
```

The non-zero values from `df` get assigned back based on flipped:

```
df.values[flipped]  # [1 5 5 3 0 4 1 0 0 0]
df.values[mask]  # [1 5 5 3 4 1 4 7 6 2]
```

```
df.values[flipped] = df.values[mask]
```

```
      a1  a2  a3  a4
row1   1   5   5   3
row2   4   1   4   4
row3   7   6   7   6
row4   2   0   0   2
```

Then the old values need overwritten with zeros:

```
df.values[~flipped] = 0
```

```
      a1  a2  a3  a4
row1   1   5   5   3
row2   4   1   4   0
row3   7   6   0   0
row4   2   0   0   0
```

---

Sort approach is similar but instead of flipping the `mask` is sorted:

```
mask = df.ne(0).values
sorted_mask = np.take_along_axis(mask, np.argsort(~mask), axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
      a1  a2  a3  a4
row1   1   0   5   3
row2   0   4   1   4
row3   0   0   7   6
row4   0   0   0   2
```

`mask`:

```
[[ True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True]
 [False False False  True]]
```

`sorted_mask`:

```
[[ True  True  True False]  # Falses are at end of the row always
 [ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True False False]
 [ True False False False]]
```

Comment: much appreciate for such detailed answer! will work on your ideas!